# Delphi, Lazarus - Listbox out of bound (0) TString

Tags: delphi, listbox, indexoutofboundsexception, lazarus, tstringlist

I simply can't seem to make any sense of the following error.

Listbox out of bound (0) TString

I have a form or window with a listbox and following code is supposed to work with it. It suppose to get a list of strings from an ini file and set to the listbox.

```
IF selectedbox1count <> 0 then
BEGIN
   FOR i:=0 to selectedbox1count-1 do
      selectedbox.items[i] := AInifile.ReadString('DATAVIEW2', 'SHIFT1CHART'+(i+1), ' ');
END;
```

But it always pops up a error message at the first instance it reaches the `selectedbox.items[i]` line. Read of ini file returns "NEW CHART 2" string. Am I missing something here?

UPDATE: `selectedbox1count` holds value from the ini file ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you that the list box `selectedbox` is empty. I would expect that the error is more like this:

> List index out of bounds (0)

That tells you that index 0 is invalid which can only mean that there are no items in the list box.

Presumably `selectedbox1count` is not in fact the number of items in the list box. Get that with `selectedbox.Count` or `selectedbox.Items.Count`.

You can only modify items that already exist. So clearly you need to add items to the rest. Do so by calling `selectedbox.AddItem` or `selectedbox.Items.Add`.

```
for i := 0 to selectedbox1count - 1 do
  selectedbox.AddItem(...);
```

Comment: Actually its `List index(0) out of bounds` I am adding list of strings to the listbox... Can I just call selectedbox.items.add(string); instead

Comment: Ok. That's the kind of thing that should bee copied verbatim. Anyway, the answer is still accurate.

Answer (score 5):

Based on your comments, you are trying to **add items** to the ListBox, but the `Items[]` property is used for **reading/modifying existing items**.

You need something more like this instead:

```
SelectedBox.Items.BeginUpdate;
try
  SelectedBox.Items.Clear;
  SelectedBox1Count := AInifile.ReadInteger(...);
  for i := 0 to SelectedBox1Count-1 do
    SelectedBox.Items.Add(AInifile.ReadString('DATAVIEW2', 'SHIFT1CHART'+(i+1), ' '));
finally
  SelectedBox.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```